# Flex + Flashdevelop

Tags: apache-flex, flashdevelop

I just want to ask: Can I use flashdevelop and opensource flex to make commercia projects ? Or I must open my source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Flex Framework to make commercial products without opening the source.  I do that with Flextras.

I assume that FlashDeveloper licenses only relate to the actual FlashDevelop source code, and do not relaet to the things you write using the IDE.

Comment: Thx :D 
I have one more question: I can use Adobe Flex SDK or only Open Source Flex SDK ?

Comment: I use the regular Adobe Flex SDK for Flextras.  You should check the licenses with your own lawyer though.